# How to style the nested firstElementChild in native Element Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have this following Structure where the there are nested child components in Parent Component and i need to lay the focus on the Child component div programmatically.

I have reproduces [this stackblitz for the above problem](https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-test).

If you see the ts file, I have done the following

```
 ngAfterViewInit(){
  console.log(this.test);
  this.test.toArray()[1].nativeElement.focus();
  this.test.toArray()[1].nativeElement.firstElementChild.nativeElement.focus(); //this dosent work
 }
```

The console.log returns me a query list of divs (in my original case a list of components) and in that I have a firstElementChild a (component) whose firstChildElement is a div I need to style and add focus on. But I am unable to do so as if you check the stacktrace it returns `Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined`.

In simple works the Structure:

*ParentComponent -> viewChild gets me Query List of Child -> the array element has components -> each component has a firstElementChild -> property that has a div that I need to put focus on*

**UPDATE**

Thanks all for your feedback and help really appreciated but now the thing is
It works but only if i give tab index for all the nested divs i was hoping that it trickles down the child the tab index. this is the problem. Any work around to this problem as this way i need to modify the template fro all my nested components in the broader sense

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
this.test.toArray()[1].nativeElement.firstElementChild.nativeElement.focus(); //this dosent work
```

to

```
this.test.toArray()[1].nativeElement.firstElementChild.focus(); //this should work :-)
```

nativeElement.firstElementChild is NOT an ElementRef but already an HTMLElement => it doesn't have a property nativeElement.

Comment: You again added a nativeElement where it souldn't be Yout tried

`this.test.toArray()[1].nativeElement.firstElementChild.nativeElement.focus(); //this dosent work`

It should ne 


`this.test.toArray()[1].nativeElement.firstElementChild.focus(); `

Comment: So which element do you want to be focused? The first child-element is a DIV, which contains the number and a nested div with the text => so the entire content is focused. Do you want the number to be focused? Then the number must be in it's own element.

Comment: i want the my test which is inside of the number that to be focused. as in my case the above will be a parent component which has child and grand child i need to focus on grand child from parent

Comment: try 


`this.test.toArray()[1].nativeElement.firstElementChild.firstElementChild.focus();`

Comment: dosent work check this link https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-test?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @INFOSYS: when replying to helpful people, try avoiding a brusque reply of "doesn't work". That does not give your helper any new information to go on. You are the eyes and ears on the problem, so it is your job to be as helpful as possible, if you want some assistance. How does it not work? What else do you observe? What things do you think you could try now?

Comment: @halfer sorry i will keep that in mind from now on , will hope to give more detail of the problem , it works but only if i give tab index for all the nested divs i was hoping that it trickles down the child the tab index. this is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, `children` property of the HTML Element will also return a  `HTMLElementCollection` as below,

```
this.test.toArray()[1].nativeElement.children[0].focus();
```

**[Updated Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-test-jvdrfj?file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: it should be `this.test.toArray()[1].nativeElement.children[0].children[0].focus(); ` as the my test will  get highlighted

Comment: Can you explain me why and how is this above comment working and why not focus , what can be the issue. I will apply this to my component and let you know if this works but i want to know why this works and others dont

Comment: It dosent work aravind as you have placed a nested `<div [tabIndex] = "1">` or in general terms a tab index on inner div can't we remove that and use

Comment: @INFOSYS so none of the answers helped you?

Comment: @Aravindit works but only if i give tab index for all the nested divs i was hoping that it trickles down the child the tab index. this is the problem

Comment: You can use the find method to find a particular tab in it

Answer (score 0):

Updated template

```
<div>
  <p> Welcome to the world of  {{testHtml}} </p>
</div>

<div *ngFor = "let i of numbers; let ii = index" [attr.tabIndex] = "ii==00 ? 0 : null" #test>
  <div>{{i}}
    <div>
      MY test
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**updated .ts file**

```
 ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.test.toArray()[0].nativeElement.focus();
 }
```

**Note:** You were using same tabindex for all the elements. You need to define tabindex for a selected one that you want to focus initally.

Comment: it works but only if i give tab index for all the nested divs i was hoping that it trickles down the child the tab index. this is the problem , but then the problem will be you cannot traverse in the respective order as you have given tab index of different type